# get a thread from another class

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a java class:

```
public class httpd implements Runnable
{

   public void createHttpdStatistics
   {
      httpdStatistics stats = new httpdStastics(this);
   }

}
```

Now I would get in another class the object `stats` created inside httpd. When httpd object starts, it execute in the jvm. I tought to build get method inside httpd class but when I'm in the other class how I get the exact httpd object to call get method to retrieve stats object?

EDIT

```
public class httpd implements Runnable
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        httpd server = new httpd();
        OtherClass oc = new OtherClass(server);
    }
{


MY OWN MAIN

public class myownmain
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //Here I need OtherClass object created in httpd class
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the code posted [here](http://pastebin.com/0jE2CYY0): 
In your other class, say `OtherClass` for example, you should have setter for `httpd` object or provide the `httpd` instance in the `OtherClass` constructor. This way `OtherClass` will have a reference to `httpd`

```
public class OtherClass{
   httpd httpd_ = null;

   public OtherClass(httpd httpd_){
      this.httpd_ = httpd_;
   }
   // Access and use stats from httpd
   public void useStats(){
      httpdStatistics stats = httpd_.getStatistics()
      if(stats != null){
        // Do something here
      }else{
        // stats not set yet, the thread did probably not start yet
      }
   }
}
```

In your application's main you can have the following:

```
httpd  h = new httpd();
OtherClass otherClass = new OtherClass(h);
```

**EDIT** As mentioned in one of the comments, the `stats` variable is shared among two threads so you will have to synchronize on it and make sure it is updated in a exclusive way.

Comment: What I didn't undestand is: how can I pass httpd instance in the OtherClass?

Comment: What is not clear if he runs this createHttpdStatistics code from the run method of the Runnable or not. If yes - then the other thread may get a null object, maybe he should coordinate between the two threads with a shared data structure (for example, a singletone ) as I suggested

Comment: @zaske thanks for pointing this out, I updated the code to ensure the code is doing the right thing when the thread has not setup `stats` yet. I am personally not in favor of using singletons as they are very bad and get your application's design down to earth. Singletons are just like global variables and should be avoided whenever possible.

Comment: Good, the `httpd` class has already a `getStatistics` method. You don't need to add that then.

Comment: @zaske from the link to code posted in the comment, the `stats` object is initialized before anything kicks off so it wouldn't be a problem :)

Comment: @GETah What I didn't undestand is: how can I use ServerMonitor object outside httpd class if I create it in the httpd class? I would use it outside

Comment: I would print out this statistics outside httpd class.

Comment: @user1508419 You should define a getter in the `httpd` class and return the instance from there

Comment: @GETah can you do me an example?

Comment: @GETah If I define a getted in httpd class how I can obtain httpd object outside?

Comment: You can get that by: `ServerMonitor sm = httpd_.getServerMonitor();`

Comment: @GETah I need to create an my own MAIN and pass inside this main ServerMonitor object created in httpd class...

Comment: @GETah please don't leave me alone...help me

Answer (score 0):

What's the problem in passing the passing the stats object to the other class you need inside a CTOR, by providing a getter to the stats object in class httpd - 
this is only of course if the createHttpdStatistics method is not executed in the code of the run method (I suggest your pvovide it). 
If the createHttpdStatistics method is executed within the run method (in a different thread)  you should consider having a shared data structure between the threads (for example - shared Singletone that can be used as a shared data structure), if you want to create the HttpdStatistics object within a thread. 
In this case the code will look like:

```
public class httpd implements Runnable
{

   public void createHttpdStatistics()
   {
      httpdStatistics stats = new httpdStastics(this);
      StatsManager.getInstance().putStats(stats);
   }

   public void run() {
      //I assume the creation is done at the run method. Maybe I'm wrong here.
      createHttpdStatistics();
   }


}
```

And then use this somewhere in your code -

```
HttpdStatistics stats = StatsManager.getInstance().getStats();
MyClass  stats = new MyClass(stats); //passing stats to another object.
```

You should of course make sure that getStats either blocks under the stats object is set to the singletone, or to check if getStats() returns null.